# Gunicorn gock file not appear

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a web server created with Django, but from one moment to another my server is down and nginx return error 502, before I create my sock file, but when I try again I can't create this.

```
pkill gunicorn
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
```

I read something about web permissions for folders but I think the folder that contains my server has all the possible permissions.

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep  8 02:17 trackerServer
```

On the other hand this is my `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/tracker-web/trackerServer/trackerServer.sock trackerServer.wsgi:application

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/django_joya/
ExecStart=gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/django_joya/joyas.sock joyas.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In the server there are 2 projects, but only `tracker-web/trackerServer` are mine, `django_joya` is the other person.

Any help please, I can not generate my sock file

**EDIT**

Here is my result when I try `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-09-08 03:00:20 UTC; 9h ago
 Main PID: 11134 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Sep 08 03:00:20 ip-172-26-13-39 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Sep 08 03:00:20 ip-172-26-13-39 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Sep 08 03:00:20 ip-172-26-13-39 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 08 03:00:20 ip-172-26-13-39 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 08 03:00:21 ip-172-26-13-39 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:15] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/django
```

Comment: type sudo systemctl status gunicorn and add the log

Comment: Try `journalctl -f -n10 -u gunicorn.service` and monitor what is happening

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I add my log in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem like the log show is the execution var, also you have 2 services, delete one. The services should look like:

```
[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myproject
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

Remember replace the gunicorn, sock, and wsgi root. More information https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#check-for-the-gunicorn-socket-file

Comment: Thanks, but I have two service in a server?